# Matlab example code for deep belief network for classification

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, classification, deep-learning

I have a dataset of 40 feature vectors divided into 4 clases. Could somebody give an example code in Matlab how to apply deep belief network to do classification (and explaining parameters)? Arbitrary library/tooblox can be used, but should be in Matlab.

There is for example shogun toolbox (http://www.shogun-toolbox.org/), DeeBNet toolbox (http://ceit.aut.ac.ir/~keyvanrad/DeeBNet%20Toolbox.html) or the deep learning toolbox (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/38310-deep-learning-toolbox) but unfortunately all of them are not very well documented and because I'm totally new to deep learning / neral nets it is really hard for me.

Edit: What should I chose for the following parameters or over what range should I search?

```
nn.activation_function              = 'tanh_opt';   %  Activation functions of hidden layers: 'sigm' (sigmoid) or 'tanh_opt' (optimal tanh).
nn.learningRate                     = 2;            %  learning rate Note: typically needs to be lower when using 'sigm' activation function and non-normalized inputs.
nn.momentum                         = 0.5;          %  Momentum
nn.scaling_learningRate             = 1;            %  Scaling factor for the learning rate (each epoch)
nn.weightPenaltyL2                  = 0;            %  L2 regularization
nn.nonSparsityPenalty               = 0;            %  Non sparsity penalty
nn.sparsityTarget                   = 0.05;         %  Sparsity target
nn.inputZeroMaskedFraction          = 0;            %  Used for Denoising AutoEncoders
nn.dropoutFraction                  = 0;            %  Dropout level (http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/dropout.pdf)
nn.testing                          = 0;            %  Internal variable. nntest sets this to one.
nn.output                           = 'sigm';       %  output unit 'sigm' (=logistic), 'softmax' and 'linear'

opts.numepochs =   1;
opts.batchsize = 100;
opts.momentum  =   0;
opts.alpha     =   1;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So DBN's are pretty complicated and it took me a few months to really wrap my head around them. Here's a quick overview though-

A neural network works by having some kind of features and putting them through a layer of "all or nothing activations". These activations have weights and this is what the NN is attempting to "learn". NNs kind of died in the 80-90's because the systems couldn't find these weights properly. This was until the awesome [2006 paper of Geoff Hinton](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/MatlabForSciencePaper.html) - who thoughy to pretrain the network with a restricted boltzman machine to get the weights in the right ball park.

It depends on your goal, but if your goal is to learn how they work, I would start with Hinton's original paper and rewrite it to have functions instead of the static 3 layer network thats in the paper. This will give you a good intuition of whats going on in terms of the weights being learned and the activations.

Now to answer your second question- there's a bit of debate- but in my experience the most key factor is coming up with the architecture of the system these variables are as follows:

- number of layers
- number of visible
- nodes  number of hidden nodes per layer

Other variables you can control are what I would classify as optimization variables. These are:

- the activation function- tanh, sigmoid, relu
- the learning rates for the variables learned

I'm going to warn you though, don't expect stellar results-- and be prepared to have a system that takes a long time to train.

A second route you could go is to try some other systems out there like Caffe and that might give you more usable results.

Anyways, good luck  :)

ps, with such small data you might consider using SVMs instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What values for the variable would you suggest? My goal is not to learn how they work. I just want to apply a deep belief net for classification on my dataset. Would it be possible that you give some example code in Matlab so that I see how it can be done? That would be really great.

Comment: To be honest, these are the things you want to test. I use the relu function where these learning rates are from 0.00001-1, and I don't remember what range they were in for tanh. However, these are optimization variables and shouldn't effect outcomes tremendously. As I said before the more important thing is to get the architecture right- the number of layers and hidden nodes. Also play with "opts", which you put in your updated code. Definitely have more than 1 for numepochs. For batchsize, well your data is less than 100, so I would change that to 1. Momentum probably should be 0.001.